# admin-ajax.php do not recognizes 'action'. $_REQUEST is empty

Tags: ajax, wordpress

After two days of fruitless research, I decided to join the community. I hope to get a solution. I develop a plug-in that, among other things, must implement the upload of documents. this should be done using ajax technology. the problem is that the request is approved, but admin_ajax.php reacts like no action was taken. Outside of  wp this piece of code works fine, as it was thought out. The problems come with installing this code in wp. Below is my code

1. PHP.  This code in the main class that will call from main modul of plugin

   ```
   class main{

    //other activation methods 

       private  function register_scripts(){

           add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'re_add_script'));

       }

       public function re_add_script() { 

           wp_enqueue_script('re_upload',plugins_url('re'.'/js/re_upload.js'),array('jquery'));

           wp_localize_script('re_upload',"re_ajax",array(
                   'ajaxurl'=>admin_url("admin-ajax.php")));

           add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload', 'processingUpload');  
      }

   }//end of class

   //callback function

   function processingUpload(){ 
        $clsUpload = new UploadsDocs();

        $clsUpload->setRequestedData($_FILES,$_POST['doc_id']);

        $clsUpload->checkUploadsFiles();

        $clsUpload->outputFilesList();

        wp_die();

   }
   ```
2. jQuery 're_upload.js'

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    jQuery('#bt_upload').on('click', function () {
        var toUpload=getFileListToUpload(); 
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var ins = input.files.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            if (isFileToUpload(input.files[x],toUpload)){
                form_data.append("files[]", input.files[x]);
            }
        }
        form_data.append("doc_id", jQuery('#doc_id')[0].value);
        var data_to_sent={
            action: 'upload',
            datas: form_data
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: re_ajax.ajaxurl, // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data_to_sent,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                // do something
            },
            error: function (response) {
                // do something
            },
            xhr: function(){
               //upload Progress
               var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
               if (xhr.upload) {
                   xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                       var percent = 0;
                       var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                       var total = event.total;
                       if (event.lengthComputable) {
                           percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                       }
                       //update progressbar
                       jQuery('#bt_upload').css("display","none");
                       jQuery('#progress-wrp').css("display","block");
                       jQuery('#progress-wrp' +" .progress-bar").css("width", + percent +"%");
                       (percent<50)? jQuery('#progress-status').addClass('status-less-then-50'): jQuery('.status-less-then-50').removeClass('status-less-then-50').addClass('status-more-then-50');
                       jQuery('#progress-status').text("Uploading..."+percent +"%");
                   }, true);
               }
               return xhr;
           },
           mimeType:"multipart/form-data" 
        });
     });
   });


   function getFileListToUpload(){
     var list=[];
     var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');
     var tag_li=elem[0].querySelectorAll('p');
     for (var i=0;i<tag_li.length;i++){
        list[i]=tag_li[i].textContent.split('(')[0];
     }
      return list;

    }

     function isFileToUpload(input_file,files_toUpload){
        var res=false;

      for(var i=0; i<files_toUpload.length;i++){
           if (input_file.name==files_toUpload[i]){
             res=true;
             break;
      }
      }
          return res;
      }
   ```

Comment: `contentType: false` - why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload', 'processingUpload');
```

is not called.

The upload is done in two separate invocations of the server. The first invocation displays the upload page to the user. The second invocation processes the AJAX request. Your call to

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_upload', 'processingUpload');
```

is done in the first invocation where it is not needed but not in the second invocation where it is needed.

Please read https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. (Observe carefully how the call to 'add_action( 'wp_ajax_...', ...) is done.) Further, you need to read about [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Comment: Thanks, but how i can different between first an second invocation recognise

Comment: The first invocation is a request for a front-end page. The hook wp_enqueue_scripts only runs in requests for front-end pages. The second request is an AJAX request. AJAX requests runs in admin mode  so is_admin() returns true. This is the conventional way to do this but even more specific conditions are possible.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable tip. It took me further. Now I want to add a little bit. Ajax query is ok, but in response  was 0 returned. I've noticed that for the upload form filter(action) wp_ajax_re_upload is set, but after ajax request was sent  it will disappear from global $ wp_filter array. Could there be something for more tips? I would be very grateful for your efforts

Comment: A 0 response means WordPress did not find the requested action. Either the add_action() was not executed, you have a spelling error or there is no logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append action to your ajax url like:

```
           url: re_ajax.ajaxurl?action=upload
```

and

```
           data: form_data
```

or pass it to form_data like:

```
        form_data.append('action', 'upload')
```